# Chevy 4.8 misfiring

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, silverado

I drove the truck through a big puddle and it killed it. Found I had completely soaked the air cleaner and had possibly got water in the intake. I replaced the filter and took contact cleaner to all the sensors. The truck won't idle above 1000 rpms with the pedal to the floor.

I hooked it a computer and it said the crank sensor was out of range, replaced the crank sensor, map sensor, and all the plugs and wires. Found that it was misfiring on #s 2 and 3. So I changed the coils and it still ain't hitting on those cylinders. Also I drained the oil and didn't find any water in the pan or the cylinders. What would be my next step aside from pulling the pan and looking at the crank?

Comment: Try a compression test to see if you hydrolocked the engine.

Comment: I take it the crank sensor code didn't return after it was replaced? Is the *completely* not firing on these two cylinders or is it intermittent? This is most likely not a mechanical issue (it didn't hydrolock IMHO), but an electrical one. Check the ground on the two coils which are not firing. Also, check to ensure there is continuity within the wiring harness from the coils all the way back to the ECU for #2 and #3 cylinders. That is is happening on either side of the engine is strange to me, making me wonder about the connection at the ECU itself.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.....the two cylinders aren't firing at all. Also I tested the harness at the pigtail using  a power probe,to the coils and found on the ground wires they would flash 0.2v just for a second then go to 0.0v. I'm wondering if getting those coils wet might have popped the PCM? Got an appointment to get it checked out later in the week. I'll definitely let u know what I find out. Again thanks for ur input. Oh it has good compression on all cylinders.